# R data.table performance - proceed line by line

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have a performance issue in R using a data.table

I have a data.table with mixed data and I need to do some simple computations proceeding line by line. Therefor I need to do a for-loop through all lines. Usually I avoid for-loops but since the computation of one line depends on the previous one - I can't avoid the for-loop.

I've build a basic example which reproduces the issue:

```
# create some sample-data
dt <- data.table(x=1:300000,y=rnorm(100),z=c("a","b","c","d"))
dt$new <- NA_integer_

# init some demo variables
xxx <- 612341
yyy <- 1 

for (i in (1:nrow(dt))){
 dt[i,new := xxx] # write something
 yyy  <- dt[i,y]  # read something

 if ((i %% 20000) == 0){print(i)} # see progress
}
```

Using system.time this runs: 230 seconds. Pretty long for very simple computations on 300.000 data-lines ...?

For performance optimization I allocate memory for the new column before the loop. Also I use the `:=` operator to avoid copying.

Is there any way to speed this up?

---

Here is the operation I am trying to compute actually.
I want to add the value of the previous line if the current line belongs to the same class.

```
dt <- data.table(x=1:30000,y=rnorm(100),z=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","d"))
dt$new <- NA_real_

remember <- NA_real_
currentclass <- ""

for (i in (1:nrow(dt)))
{
  if (dt[i,z] == currentclass)
  {
    dt[i,new := remember]
    remember <- dt[i,y]
  }
  else
  {
    currentclass <- dt[i,z]
    remember <- dt[i,y]
    dt[i,new := NA]
  }
}
```

Comment: It's good that you provided a simple, reproducible example, but in this case, you should probably also include an example of the actual operation that you are performing (assuming the above is an over-simplification), just because the translation of an iterative operation to a vectorized equivalent will most likely be context specific.

Comment: instead of using `for` loop you could do this `dt[i,new := xxx, by = 1:nrow(dt)]`

Comment: Is `dt[,new:=NA^c(TRUE,z[-1]!=z[-nrow(dt)])*c(NA,y[-nrow(dt)])]` what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you @nicola this is a very smart solution for my problem. Besides this specific problem I'm wondering if there is a general solution: I used to write a lot of SAS-scripts and this processing 'line by line' can be done in SAS easily&fast in a data-step. Is there a good/fast way to do this in R or is it always about vectorisation?

Comment: The general solution is to learn to think the "R way" instead of the "SAS way". It's basically always an error to move the same logic from a programming language to another. You thought that your problem wasn't suited for vectorization and should only be approached with the "line-by-line" paradigm. You were wrong. You will learn to abandon your SAS schemes to make fast R code.